# Notification icon on mobile app only home screen?

Tags: usability, mobile, mobile-application

I am designing an Artisan app, I want to know, is notification show only on home screen? or we can show notification icon on every screen.  I saw multiple mobile apps they don't show notification icons in latest mobile app. so  I have two questions:

1. on which screen we need to show notification icon
2. What is the latest trends of apps? to show notification or not?

Answer (score 1):

One good practice that I am seeing more and more is to make a page of all notifications and the link to the list should be in the main navigation (the bell icon should be in the main navigation). When the notification list is populated with new items, the bell icon, which should be present on all pages as it part of the main navigation, will display a red circle (or something of that sort). This will allow the user to check notifications only when they want to instead of being distracted by them on every page.